# Is V-TEC Reliable?

Tags: engine, honda, vtec

I'm thinking of purchasing a 2001 Honda Civic that has v-tec on the side panel of the drivers side.

Are V-TEC engines reliable, and are they well known for performance?

The car I'm thinking of has 300,000 kms on it. Will it be worn out by this time?

Comment: Unfortunately, opinion based questions are not really a fit for Stack Exchange. If' you'd like to ask these types of questions, you can hit up the regulars over on [The Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop), which is this site's chat room. We can talk about things a lot more freely there.

Comment: The civic had 8 different engine choices worldwide.  They vary from 1.5 to 1.8 liter.

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question, though it is probably way too broad. Honda claims that there has never been a warranty claim against their VTEC systems - as in, the solenoids and variable valve/timing system is quite reliable.

This isn't at all to say that these engines don't fail - of course they do - however they have a very good track record for reliability *if maintained correctly*. However gaskets, rings, bearings etc can all still fail as with any other engine.

Any car with 300,000kms on it is going to be due for repairs.

Please note, however. An awful lot of civics get given VTEC badges when they don't have variable timing. You should *always* look beyond the sticker on the outside of the car. Look under the hood, look at the engine, do some research on the car.

Comment: It's easy to yell from the VIN whether the engine in question is actually a VTEC or not

Comment: @BobCross The seventh generation Civic wasn't a hugely popular tuning platform, but considering the popularity and availability of engine swaps, I wouldn't trust the VIN on a 15 y/o Civic for anything more than discerning the trim level.

Comment: @MooseLucifer the VIN is molded into the engine. That's the number I'm specifically referring to.

Comment: @BobCross That's still unreliable, see 'mini-me' swap.

Comment: Hey guys, the Vin is stamped on the cars body, though the engine number is on the block. Once an engine is swapped, the paperwork surrounding the car doesn't always get updated. It's not uncommon to have a twin cam in a car that came out with a d15b, or have a base level stocker that's badged like a type r. It's why you never buy a car sight-unseen, paperwork often lies ;)

Answer (score 2):

Honda used VTEC for two applications:

1. Fuel economy. For example the [F18B engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_F_engine#F18B) with peak power of 136 shp. Rev limit of about 6000 rpm. Sometimes called i-VTEC.
   Performance is decent but not spectacular (many have low torque at low rpm so you need to shift down for overtaking).
2. Performance. For example the F20C engine from the S2000, with ~230 shp. Rev limit 9000 rpm. Cars using performance VTEC are often called Type-R. 
   Rocketships, again with power concentrated at high rpm.

Either application could be in the Honda you're looking at.

Honda has a good reputation for reliability.

Comment: FWIW, my '94 Civic Hybrid had i-VTEC. Definitely not for performance reasons!

Answer (score 0):

I have a 94 Acura Integra with the DOHC VTEC engine (B18C1).  Just passed 350,000 miles.  Still runs good, I take it to the red line at least once a week when its nice out.  If you maintain it, it will run.

Answer (score 0):

I own two, count 'em, two Honda Civics. One is a 2003 Civic EX while Civic number two is a 2012 Si. Both are great cars. The '03 is bullet proof has low miles for the year ( 158,000 ) and has only required routine maintenance and the occasional light bulb. It feels new. I highly recommend the 7th gen.

The '012 Si is like the EX's rowdy brother. It has the 2.4 and lots of torque. Love it. The gas mileage is 32-33 mpg vs. the '03's 40 mpg. It has a timing chain. No timing belt changes.

Civics are a reliable as anything out there. Just do your maintenance, fill it up and then? Drive! And yes, the Vtec's are reliable. The '03 will pull strongly when the gas pedal is pressed down with its small 1.7 litre engine, don' even ask about the SI. It is a rocket ship.